# About Laravel Webpack Mix and the extract method

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-5.8

I have a question about Laravel Webpack Mix on the version of Laravel 5.8.

Is it mandatory to include **Vue/jQuery** in app.js using the Webpack Mix extract method?

This will not duplicate when loading the **manifest.js/vendor.js/app.js** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Webpack and [Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix#vendor-extraction) are smart enough, and won't result in duplicate code.